Uno Platform App shows a blank screen on other devices
I finished writing my app using Uno Platform. It works perfectly well on my PC. I packaged the Release version of the app into a .msix package. I installed this package and it works perfectly well on my PC.
Unfortunately, when I copy the file over to my other PC, it installs but when I launch the app, I get a blank screen.
I actually learned about the blank screen from Microsoft. I submitted the app to the Microsoft Partner program and they responded with this message:
They see a blank screen.
How do I fix this?
